# State/Country jquery drop down not working with selectbox 0.2 min.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, selector

I am running PHP with a JS selectbox 0.2 min.js. I have an address form which I'd like to work like this. The first drop down displays countries. If US or Canada is selected, it displays a dropdown of states for those countries.  If not, it hides the state drop down and produces an input box where you type in the state/region/etc.

The below code (and many similar snippets I've found) works in jsfiddle, but I cant get it to work correctly in my script - it won't unhide ca box1, us box1, or any box1. The display:none persists in each case.  I believe this has to do with the select box that is used elsewhere on the page and perhaps overriding css but am not sure.

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php if(!$this->address) { ?>
    <div class="address_layout">
        <?php $ind = 0;?>
        <?php foreach($this->addresses as $address) { ?>
            <!-- current address(es) -->
            <div id="address_<?php echo $ind; ?>" style="display:none;">

        <div>
            <select id="country">
                <option value="">choose country</option>
                <option value="ca">Canada</option>
                <option value="us">USA</option>
                <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="ca box1">
            <strong>Canada  Province Select Box...</strong>
            <br />
            <select>
                <option>canada 1</option>
                <option>canada 2</option>
                <option>canada 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="us box1">
            <strong>United States State Select Box</strong>
            <br />
            <select>
                <option>usa 1</option>
                <option>usa 2</option>
                <option>usa 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="any box1">Enter your Region:
            <br />
            <input name="state" type="text" />
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>





    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#country").change(function(){
            $(".box1").hide();
            $("." + this.value).toggle(['ca','us'].indexOf(this.value)!=-1);
            $(".any").toggle(['ca','us'].indexOf(this.value)==-1);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: if its css issue then use different style names make it particular case. i tried in jsfiddle and on my pc  works fine. give more information that will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Hashy. I'm not sure if it is CSS issue but when I inspect element, it says sbHolder is the class, which leads me to believe the select box creates a parent class. I'm just not sure how to override it. BTW, this is all in a form. I'm adding the form parameters above. Also, there is some other javascript on the page. Could it be they are interfering with each other? Tx.